# Use numbers of ttfamily

Tags: fonts, numbering

I like the lining figures of the `\ttfamily`.

I would like to use them within math mode, as equation numbering and within tikzpicutres.

Concerning math mode, I use `amsmath` and could display numbers the way I want it when putting them into `\texttt{123546789}`, but this is a tiring solution. Same with `$...$`.

When placing a tikzpicture like this:

```
\begin{figure}
\ttfamily
\input{test.tikz}}
\end{figure}
```

the style of the numbering of the axis won't change.

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{pgfplots} %for tikzpictures:
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[osf,sc]{mathpazo} %the font I use

\begin{document}
In math-mode:
\begin{align}
U=123456890\\ 
U=\texttt{123456890}\\
U=\mathtt{123456890}
\end{align}
The default figure style should be like in equation 0.2 and 0.3. 
\\
The equation numbering on the right side should be in this style: \texttt{(0.1)} \texttt{(0.2)} \texttt{(0.3)}
\\
Same with dollarsign-enviorment, the latter 2 should be default: 
$U=123456890$ $U=\texttt{123456890}$ $U=\mathtt{123456890}$
\begin{figure}
\ttfamily %makes only the labeling in \ttfamily, but I want labeling and numbering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
width=10cm,
height=10cm,
scale only axis,
xmin=0,
xmax=10,
xlabel={4 5 6},
ymin=0,
ymax=20,
ylabel={8 10 12},
axis x line*=bottom,
axis y line*=left,
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Do you want typewriter type numbers in *all* math?

Comment: @egreg Yes, in all math!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I find it bizarre (not to say ugly); but the document is yours. I hope that when you'll see the result, you'll change your mind.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{pgfplots} %for tikzpictures:
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[osf,sc]{mathpazo} %the font I use

\sbox0{$\mathtt{\xdef\mathttfam{\the\fam}}$}
\newcommand\dottnumber[1]{%
  \mathcode`#1=\numexpr\mathcode`#1-"7000+"\mathttfam00\relax
}
\dottnumber{0}\dottnumber{1}\dottnumber{2}\dottnumber{3}\dottnumber{4}%
\dottnumber{5}\dottnumber{6}\dottnumber{7}\dottnumber{8}\dottnumber{9}%
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tagform@[1]{\maketag@@@{($#1$)}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
In math-mode:
\begin{align}
U=123456890\\ 
U=\texttt{123456890}\\
U=\mathtt{123456890}
\end{align}
The default figure style should be like in equation 0.2 and 0.3. 
\\
The equation numbering on the right side should be in this style: \texttt{(0.1)} \texttt{(0.2)} \texttt{(0.3)}
\\
Same with dollarsign-enviorment, the latter 2 should be default: 
$U=123456890$ $U=\texttt{123456890}$ $U=\mathtt{123456890}$
\begin{figure}
\ttfamily %makes only the labeling in \ttfamily, but I want labeling and numbering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=10cm,
height=10cm,
scale only axis,
xmin=0,
xmax=10,
xlabel={4 5 6},
ymin=0,
ymax=20,
ylabel={8 10 12},
axis x line*=bottom,
axis y line*=left,
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you really want to use Courier together with Palatino, a combination which I'm not bold enough to show a picture of, add, before the line starting with `\sbox0`,

```
\usepackage{courier}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathtt}{OT1}{\ttdefault}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathtt}{bold}{OT1}{\ttdefault}{b}{n}
```

Remember to use `\eqref` if you want that references to equation numbers are in the typewriter font.

> Please, don't inflict this to your readers

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Though I did not really understand what you did. So, when I want to change my ttfamily like this: `\usepackage{courier}`
`\renewcommand*{\ttdefault}{pcr}`, the numbers will not change accordingly.

Comment: @jonen No, they won't. I'll show you how to do it. However, using typewriter type numbers in Computer Modern is ugly, in Courier it's abominable. `;-)` Combining Courier with Palatino will make Hermann Zapf cry.

Comment: Thanks. Don't worry, I am just messing around with different typewriter fonts.

Comment: As an explanation: I am forced to do very boring, monotonous protocols, therefore I think using typewriter fonts is very suiting. I want to express my anger not with horrible mixture of fonts but with the very bureaucratic monotonous and very exact feel that I associate with typewriters.